# Get Range of Document Property in Body

Tags: office-js, office-addins

In Word, I am adding custom document properties to the body of the document, whose values' are strings.  From my add-in, I'd like to access these properties.  Is there some method from the api to access the document properties that have been inserted to the body of the word document?

It is straightforward to access the document properties, but I can't find any relavent api documentation on finding document properties that have actually been inserted into the body.

Currently, I am running a search for the property's value to see if it has been inserted.  However, this search may return instances that are not actually a document property. For example, if I have a custom document property whose value is "hello", and the body of my document is "hello hello", a search will return both instances, even if these strings weren't inserted as fields.

Any direction on possible solutions to this are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you can load the `values` of the [DocumentProperties.customProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word_release/word.documentproperties?view=office-js#customproperties) and then loop through them looking for "hello".